# Trying to add System Parachain

Tags: parachain, substrate-parachain-template

I am trying to add a system parachain, I am able to register parathread and slots are leased but the blocks are not being finalized.
Call for registering system parachain - [image]

parathread registered - [image]

Terminal - [image]

Is this the way the right way to add system parachain?
If yes where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, parathread can't produce any blocks.

You need to make it a parachain.

You should use this on your testnet.

[image]

Comment: This is for normal parachains, I want to add a system parachain. How can we do for system parachains?

Comment: What's the differences between normal parachain and system parachain?

Comment: System parachains are common good parachains(trusted) like statemint is for polkadot and statemine for kusama network. I want to add this system parachain through governance.

Comment: Statemint and statemine are just some normal parachains in this view. There aren't any differences about how to add it as a parachain.

Check https://polkadot.polkassembly.io/referendum/46.

Just like other parachains. Add the shell chain and upgrade it. Or add this chain directly.

Comment: IIUC, "common good parachain" is just a sort of service/marketing requirement. It doesn't affect the relaychain-parachain protocol. You can make some runtime configurations for those parachains, like zero tx fee, a special para id, ...

Comment: How can I add a parachain through governance i.e. without sudo?

Comment: That's another question. Check https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/how-would-someone-go-without-the-sudo-pallet.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful.