# Horizontally scaling one chain

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

Is it possible to combine a relay chain with several compatible parachains to create one single logical chain with shared account balances?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Polkadot has [System Parachains](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-system-chains).

Moving logic in parachains instead of the Relay Chain, Polkadot uses its own scaling technology to host itself. System parachains remove transactions from the Relay Chain, allowing more Relay Chain blockspace to be used for Polkadot's primary purpose: validating parachains.

In this article [Common Good Parachains](https://medium.com/polkadot-network/common-good-parachains-an-introduction-to-governance-allocated-parachain-slots-88e01812160d) Joe mention something similar as your use case, using one System Parachain just to manage the balances.

> Examples of potential system level chains include parachains for
> balances, elections (for both staking and Council), governance, and
> identity. Eventually, the Relay Chain could become transactionless, as
> in, it would only validate parachain state transitions and all of its
> current transactional functionality would exist within parachains.

And example of a System Parachain on Polkadot today is [Statemint](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus#statemint-), which is an asset portal for the entire network.

To add a System Parachain in your Relay Chain you have [to add it through governance](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/trying-to-add-system-parachain), see this [old question on StackExchange](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2283/2762) to see how to do it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your answer. Would the use of a dedicated system parachain be a one-time upgrade or can multiple system parachains work together to scale balance transactions horizontally? Is the machinery already in place to achieve this, or must we get clever, perhaps by sharding accounts somehow?